# How can I use the name "A Google user" in my reviews at Google Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store, privacy

I have seen many recent reviews (2017) in Google Play Store with the name "A Google user" and I'd like to know how one can do that. I've read some possibilities, but they were written in 2012 and now you can't do it anymore due to changes in G services. Is it possible to do without creating a dummy user?

Answer (score 5):

**Edit**: As of August 2016, it is no longer required to have a Google Plus Profile to leave a comment in Google Play Store.

However, it would *still* require great sacrifices to comment anonymously in Google Play Store as you have to [remove your Google+ Profile](http://plus.google.com/downgrade) and as long as you create one again, all your "previously anonymous" comments will immediately be linked back to your new G+ profile.

Previously,

> <s>Due to Google's requirement since November 2012, a Google+ profile is **required** to leave comments under contents from Google Play Store, as is discussed [here](/q/86166). All those comments from anonymous users without a Google+ Profile are left before Nov, 2012.</s>

Comment: not possible to remove Google+ profile any longer using the link provided. No idea how to post reviews in Google Play anonymously now, despite the fact that I can see anonymous reviews for this app posted as recently as April 2020. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackupPro